# how to get timezone offset from tz name of the timezone to UTC

Tags: javascript, timezone

I am using tz names of timezone. Such as `Asia/Tbilisi`.

So I have this string stored in a variable. `const timezone = Asia/Tbilisi`

Now, I am curious what's the offset Difference between this timezone to UTC.

How can I do that by using pure javascript ?

Comment: You can't get *the* offset for a time zone.  You can only get *an* offset for a time zone *at a particular point in time*.  Is that what you meant? Even `Asia/Tbilisi` isn't just UTC+4.  It is *now*, but [in the past it has been UTC+3, UTC+4, and UTC+5](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/georgia/tbilisi?syear=2000&eyear=2020).  Which offset you use depends on which date and time you are evaluating.